# Oracle SQL Dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table called `Table1`, where I've a column with numbers. Those numbers are employees. And I've other column with a string like this `8,8,8,8,8,0,0`. This string are the number of hours that they work per day of the week, Monday, Tuesday... And I have another column with the year that is valid this hours, because we change this parameter every year.

I would need to obtain the following tables result between two dates:

First:
Columns:
Date ; number of employee1; number of employee2;...
In there, the date is the date and in the number of employee the data should be the corresponding hour depending of the day of the week depending on the date.

Second:
Columns:
Date, ID, Hours

In there the date should be the date, ID should be the employee´s number, and in the Hours columns should be the value of the string depending of the day of the week depending on the date

Example:

First:

```
Date || 001 || 002 || 003 ||
01/01/14 || 8 || 5 || 8
02/01/14 || 8 || 0 || 0
```

Second:

```
Date || ID || Hours
01/01/14 || 001 || 8
01/01/14 || 002 || 5
01/01/14 || 003 || 8
02/01/14 || 001 || 8
02/01/14 || 002 || 0
02/01/14 || 003 || 0
```

I'm trying to use this query to obtain the dates between two dates:

```
select (to_date('DATEFROM', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS') + rownum -1) as "Date",
to_char(to_date('DATEFROM', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS') + rownum -1, 'D') as numday,
to_char(to_date('DATEFROM', 'yyyy/MM/dd HH24:MI:SS') + rownum -1, 'Dy') as day
from Table1
where rownum <= 
to_date('DATETO', 'yyyy/MM/dd  HH24:MI:SS')-to_date('DATEFROM', 'yyyy/MM/dd  HH24:MI:SS')+1
order by (to_date('DATEFROM', 'yyyy/MM/dd  HH24:MI:SS') + rownum -1) asc
```

which with you get the column with the dates. But I can't get the complete results that I need.

Can you help me?

Comment: `'DATEFROM'` is a string literal not a column name, `DATEFROM` is a column name. Plus: using `to_date()` on a column that is defined as `DATE` in order to convert it to a `DATE` is totally **useless** - in fact it's an error waiting to happen. You should remove all those unnecessary `to_date()` calls

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The format for DATEFROM and DATETO is like the example: 2014-09-01 00:00:00  I need to do that way, and the query works.

Comment: A `DATE` column does ***NOT*** have "a format".

Comment: Ok. Thanks again for the comment. But this is NOT the key of my question.

Comment: It might very well be. Due to the useless conversion from a date to a varchar and back to a date, the actual value being used might not be the one that is stored in the column.

Comment: your table names and column names in the first parts of your question do not match with the ones in the last code sample, and the single quotes around DATEFROM are confusing and not necessary. You might want to try using a [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) example to clarify your use case.

Comment: Your data violates the [first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) by storing multiple hours numbers as a string. Hence the query problems. I hope you're an innocent victim of legacy code here. If you have any chance, try getting this into a proper relational structure, e.g. `(year, day_of_week, hours)`.

Comment: The query code that i´ve written is only for obtein a column with the dates between two dates. I´m using it as my start point to obtein the rest. I wrote it just like orientation.

Comment: Do not use `rownum` in your queries to find 'previous' / 'next' rows, if possible. Use the date instead, something like `where date_column BETWEEN some_date AND ADD_DAY(some_date + 1)`. Take a look at functions `substr` to cut the unfortunate hours string.

Comment: Why do you focus in the dates format?, I need the unfortunate hours in the development of my app. Please can we focus in the real problem?. I appreciate very much your comments but i think this is not the question.